# postgress still showing in apt update even after uninstall

Tags: apt, ppa

I have uninstall postgress sql from my machine with command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
sudo apt-get purge postgresql*
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-doc postgresql-common
```

but when I do `sudo apt-get update`, I still see postgress:

```
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:15 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease <---                                                                                                   
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease
```

How can I remove this and everything related to postgress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the PostgreSQL source from your `apt` list. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to do via the Terminal. Here's how you do it:

1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
2. Change directories to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

   ```
   cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   ```
3. List the files in that directory:

   ```
   ll
   ```

   You will see something like this:

   ```
   total 16
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 13:19 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep  9 13:00 ../
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  143 Aug 24 13:19 elementary.list
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Aug 24 13:19 patches.list
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Aug 24 14:18 postgres.list
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** The `.list` file for PostgreSQL may be different on your system, as it depends on how you installed the software.</sup>
4. Now you have two options to choose from:

   1. Delete the PostgreSQL `.list` file:

      ```
      sudo rm -f postgres.list
      ```
   2. Comment out the repository contained in the `.list` file:

      ```
      sudo vi postgres.list
      ```

      <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use a different editor. The use of `vi` here is personal preference, not an explicit recommendation.</sup>

      When the file is open, add a `#` character to the start of every line. This will comment-out the repository.
5. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Now you should see that the PostgreSQL repository is no longer part of the update collection.

Comment: this works!, I also remove pgadmin 4, to remove every postgres